# Debian Squeeze guest running under KVM, how to get serial?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, serial

I've just got it running on Ubuntu, have installed everything but the kitchen sink.

Got virt-console, virt-manager, running debian Squeeze, everything works.

But... I don't want to connect via vnc. I want to install loads of KVM's onto a headless server. And I don't want to deal with firewalling vnc.

But I can't figure out the correct way to enable serial tty access, I would ideally like for every guest machine there would be a corresponding tty on the host.

I can't figure out what I should connect getty to in the guest. Running lshw doesn't reveal any serial devices. Grub 2 doesn't make it particularly easy to figure out where to add the kernel console setting to the initrd

The guest machine has the following pty config.

```
<serial type='pty'>
   <target port='0'/>
</serial>
```

Answer (score 4):

in RHEL/Fedora I add `console=ttyS0` to the grub kernel boot line in grub.conf

Then make sure the VM xml definitions have

```
<serial type='pty'>  
 <target port='0'/> 
</serial>  
<console type='pty'>  
 <target type='serial' port='0'/> 
</console>
```

Start the VM and run `virsh list` to get it's name or number

Then simply run `virsh console $VMNAME`

I think this should work in Debian as well

Comment: Simple when you know how ;-)

Comment: I googled it up when I was writing a set of scripts to access a RHEV/oVirt guest serial console :)

Comment: On debian it's /etc/default/grub - that's why I couldn't find it. As if grub2 isn't convoluted enough already, they have to add their own little tweak to it's structure.

Comment: Then run - sudo update-grub2

Comment: I also uncommented - GRUB_TERMINAL=console

Comment: Well, I keep away from anything but RHEL/Fedora when it comes to KVM and libvirt (too many weird issues all over the place), so I don't really know how it is these days.